# Generate a URL to Rally objects using FormattedID?

Tags: rally

I would like to write web pages that have links to Rally issues (Test Cases, Defects, etc).  I would like to be able to generate a URL with the FormattedID.  Is this possible?  Or do I really need the objectID?  For example:

http://rally1.rallydev.com/363953481d/detail/testcase/TC1665

(or something like that, instead of the cryptic object id)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following allows users to go directly to the detail page of a work product without having to know the Object ID:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords=US1234

This relies on a feature of Rally's search functionality and isn't officially supported - so the above URL isn't guaranteed to work forever. However it's a decent way to use Formatted ID's as a workaround.

Comment: The situation that this does not work is when the Artifact (Test Case, Story) is contained in a different workspace than the person who clicked on it.

Comment: Good point, thanks Charles. FormattedID's are unique per workspace, not gloabally unique - so that URL will be workspace-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Searching by just keyword will give you the item with that ID and related items (e.g. other items that mention the desired ID in their name). Sometimes this is fine, sometimes not.

To search for DE75700 and DE72760 only, and no others use

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords=FormattedID%3ADE75700%20FormattedID%3ADE72760
```

This is equivalent to manually typing

```
FormattedID:DE75700 FormattedID:DE72760
```

in the Rally search box.

Comment: StayOnTarget, thanks for the edit. Though the question is about URLs I should have mentioned that UI equivalent.

Comment: There has been an update to the Rally interface.

The correct syntax is now "FormattedID:DE75700 OR FormattedID:DE72760"
and so the URL changes to "rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords=FormattedID%3ADE75700%20OR%20FormattedID%3ADE72760"

Answer (score 0):

As a corollary to the [main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13713310/3195477) I have defined a **Chrome browser bookmark** which will take me right to any Rally item by its ID.

[image]

The URL for this bookmark in full is:

```
javascript:(function(){window.location = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords=" + prompt("Enter ID:");})();
```

When this bookmark is activated, it prompts you like so:

[image]

I find this to be a huge time saver.

Thanks to [Displaying a prompt from javascript Chrome bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17920552/3195477).