# Displaying a prompt from javascript Chrome bookmark

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

I want to create a chrome bookamrk that prompts the user for a value (and then sets that value in a cookie).

I am unable to get the prompt to display. Is there a way to do this?

Current code:

```
javascript:(function(){var days=window.prompt("Number of days", "d"); var daysInHours=   24*days; document.cookie='clockoffset=PT' + daysInHours + 'H0M';})()
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Although it appears you can't run scripts like this on the new-tab page.

Comment: That is the answer. Move into answer and  I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you cannot run bookmarklets from the Chrome new tab page.

If you want to do something from there then take a look at writing a [Chrome Application](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html).

Comment: For anyone finding this later, bookmarklets are working on the new tab page as of at least Chrome v70 on macOS.

Answer (score 5):

In chrome, right click on the bookmark bar and choose **Add Page**

Give the bookmark a name and paste the following code (adjusted for your requirements) into the **URL** field

```
javascript:(function(){var site = prompt('Website?');var link = `https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=${site}`;window.location.href = link;})();
```